# Android AsyncTask Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Why i am getting this error when i use this code in the `asynctask` even i am using  `runOnUiThread()` this is the code i am using ( i am using fragments ).

```
private class GmailXMPP_AfterLogin extends AsyncTask<AfterLogging, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog _dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {          
        super.onPreExecute();
        _dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());     
        _dialog.setCancelable(false);
        _dialog.setTitle("colors");
        //((ProgressDialog)dialog).setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        _dialog.setMessage("Your content is loading.. \nPlease wait..");
        _dialog.setIndeterminate(false);         
        _dialog.show();
        //ProgressBar_show();
        Log.i(TAG, " GmailXMPP_AfterLogin onPreExecute" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void feed) {
        //ProgressBar_hide();       
        _dialog.dismiss();
        Log.i(TAG, " GmailXMPP_AfterLogin onPostExecute" );
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(AfterLogging... arg0) {

        Log.i(TAG, " GmailXMPP_AfterLogin doInBackground" );
        AfterLogging after = arg0[0];
        final XMPPConnection _connection = after.getConn();
        final String Uname = after.getAcc_Name();

                //synchronized (contactJids) {
        Roster roster = Gtalk_xmpp_client.getRoster();
        String file_name;
        for (RosterEntry entry : roster.getEntries()) {
            if (entry.getType() == ItemType.to || entry.getType() == ItemType.both) {

                boolean yes = Contact_data_source.checkUsername(entry.getUser());
                Log.i(TAG, "Con=" + yes);
                if (!yes) {

                    Bitmap buddy_img = buddyImage(entry, _connection);
                    if (buddy_img != null)
                        file_name = Store(buddy_img);
                    else
                        file_name = "";
                    if (entry.getName() == null)
                        Contact_data_source.createContact( entry.getUser(), entry.getUser(), Uname, file_name, UsedStrings.GoogleAccount );
                    else
                        Contact_data_source.createContact( entry.getName(), entry.getUser(), Uname, file_name, UsedStrings.GoogleAccount );
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Con=exist");
                }
            }
        }               
        return null;
    }
 }
```

logcat shows

```
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:101)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:63)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:80)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:76)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at com.pipemedia.fragments.ChatAccountsFragment$GmailXMPP_AfterLogin.onPreExecute(ChatAccountsFragment.java:372)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at com.pipemedia.fragments.ChatAccountsFragment.Gtalk_logInComplete(ChatAccountsFragment.java:435)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at com.pipemedia.xmpp.GmailXmppClient.Login(GmailXmppClient.java:60)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at com.pipemedia.fragments.ChatAccountsFragment$GmailXMPP.doInBackground(ChatAccountsFragment.java:337)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at  com.pipemedia.fragments.ChatAccountsFragment$GmailXMPP.doInBackground(ChatAccountsFragment.java:1)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
12-01 11:59:21.549: E/AndroidRuntime(16595):    ... 4 more
```

this is the line creating error

```
line 372 : progress_dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

Comment: you can try  `Your_Current_Activity.this` instead of `getActvitiy()`

Comment: i am using this code in fragments, so i am unable to use like that.

Comment: ok then you will need to move `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){//your code}` code from `doinBackground` to in `onPostExtecute`

Comment: i have to show progress bar in loading time, if i do like what u said there is no use of using asynctask here.

Comment: but why you are using `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()` within doInbackground . i think in current code you are not updating any UI elements from doInbackground ?

Comment: i removed this getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() still it gives errors,same above error.

Comment: post your latest catlog and also latest code

Comment: updated with latest code and logcat..

Comment: remove runonUIthread and then show your logcat @RajaReddyPolamReddy

Comment: @altaf i did that,i was updated my question with new code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probablly you called AsyncTask.execute() in a background thread.

You can only execute AsyncTask in UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

asynctask is a thread which run in background and update the ui thread only one time at last when it finish but runnable thread is not like asynctask, runnable thread calls the handler to  updated the ui thread in a loop so you cannot put handler inside the asynctask.

Comment: doinbackground--> getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a progress dialog in ongoing task which is already run in the thread then try this way.May it helps to you ::

```
Handler mHandler=new Handler();

mHandler.post(new Runnable() 
{
     public void run()
     {
          //SHOW PROGRESS DIALOG HERE                           
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SplashScreen.this, "Please wait...", "Porcessing ...", true);
```

in Activity class where you are launching AsyncTask.